# PHP failed opening required when running composer install

Tags: php, symfony, kunstmaan

When I run

```
/usr/local/bin/php54-cli -d memory_limit=-1 -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir="" composer.phar install
```

I get error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/admin/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/admin/app/console on line 10
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

It's very strange because file:

```
/home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/admin/app/bootstrap.php.cache
```

exists

I also try run:

```
/usr/local/bin/php54-cli -d memory_limit=-1 -d disable_functions="" composer.phar install
```

Then I get:

```
  [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                        
  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/bin/php54) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/katalogas/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear54)
```

What can be wron with my: `open_basedir` configuration ?

Comment: Maybe your `composer.lock` file is outdated, can you try with `composer.phar update` instead of `install`? Beware that it will update your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of late I hope this will help someone with a similar issue and GOOGLE brings them here.

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47200) on the arch Linux bug tracker while researching virtually the same problem, the solution worked for me.

copy /etc/php/php.ini to /etc/php/php-cli.ini

edit /etc/php/php-cli.ini

remove all directories from open_basedir leave uncommented

those programs that use the CLI PHP will use php-cli.ini and web server will use php.ini. Caveat emptor, this solution was used on a development system so I am not sure of the security implications. Your mileage may vary.